# Linux command to find a directory and go there

Tags: linux

I would like to find the directory which keeps a certain file and cd there. e.g.

```
find * -name hello.txt
```

output: Documents/Projects/hello.txt

```
cd Documents/Projects
```

How do I pipe these commands? Thanks!

Comment: what would you want to do if find locates more than one copy of hello.txt ?

Comment: good question! just goto the location of the first dir which holds hello.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
cd $(dirname$(find /path -name hello.txt | head -n 1))
```

or

```
cd $(find /path -name hello.txt | head -n 1 | xargs dirname)
```

You'll need to provide a `path` to search, `*` in your above wouldn't work as the shell would expand it.

EDIT and if you have spaces in your filenames

```
cd $(find /home -name 'he llo.txt' -print0 -quit | xargs -0 dirname)
```

and if you have spaces in your directory names too

```
 cd "$(find /path -name 'hello.txt' -print0 -quit | xargs -0 dirname)"
```

Comment: `dirname`, not `basename`.

Comment: thanks Iain, but now i'm getting "usage: dirname path".

Comment: adding quotations solves it. however, your solution does not work for directories whose names have spaces in them. do you know how that could be done? thanks!

Comment: Put quotes around the subshell `"$( find ...)"`

Comment: awesome, well done!

Answer (score 8):

Instead of finding all and `head -1`, just use `-quit` option to make `find` command stop after the first `hello.txt` file was found:

```
$ cd $(dirname $(find /path -name hello.txt -print -quit))
```

Comment: oooh - `-quit` I like that